# Suspend does not work on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: suspend

On a HP Probook 450 g2 laptop with 15.04 suspend worked fine.
I updated to 15.10 and when I select suspend I cannot resume.
Leds remain on and fan is working.
I have to restart the laptop.
I thought that suspend was a solved issue.
Any help?
Thanks in advance,
Konstantinos

Comment: What does sudo pm-suspend do?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and in my case my Toshiba Tecra A11 resumes after opening and closing the laptop-lid twice or maybe three times...